# How many combinations of students possible?

Tags: combinatorics

We have 1000 students and want to know what the maximum number of combinations there are of student groups where there are 3 students in each group and no student can ever be in a group with a student that they have already been in a group with. Order does not matter.

For example: If students are named as bob, ted, tom, bill, sally, alice, anna, etc then the possible groups are [bob, ted, tom], [bob, bill, sally], [bob, alice, anna] ...and now let's say in creating possible groups for student ted given this sequence, then we know ted cannot be in a group with student bob or tom, but can with student bill. But because student bill has been in a group with sally, then sally would not be eligible to be in a group with ted and bill, but anna could be an option. Eligibility of a student allowed in a group is determined by whether they have already been in a group with the students in the group to which they are being evaluated for. Depending on the configuration of students in groups, some students will no longer be able to be in a group with others.  So given this logic, how many combinations are possible?

Comment: Could you please explain what "has been in a group with" means?  How *exactly* is "eligibility" determined?

Comment: @whuber added clarification on what has been in a group means and eligibility. Please let me know if anything else unclear.

Comment: That is helpful, thank you. But could you be more specific? It sounds like you begin with one (or more?) partitions $S=\cup S_i$ of a set $S$ of students into groups $S_i$ (thus, $S_i\cap S_j=\emptyset$ when $i\ne j$) and you ask, how many partitions $S=\cup T_j$ are there for which $S_i \cap T_j$ has at most one member for all $i$ and $j$? But do you assume the partitions are homogeneous in the sense that all $T_j$ have the same numbers of elements (and likewise for the $S_i$)? If so, obviously there are *no* partitions of 1000 students into groups of 3, because 1000 is not divisible by 3.

Comment: Correct, all partitions are homogeneous in that there can only be 3 elements. And in this case, there are 1000 students and each group has 3 elements, but what I want to understand is given the rule that ∩  has at most one member for all  and , then what are the highest number of distinct groups possible? To begin answering this question, I imagined there were only 10 students and I gave each student a name corresponding to the numbers 0-9. I manually created groupings to see how many groups would be possible assuming that student 0 had to be placed first so: [0,1,2], [0,3,4]...

Comment: But @whuber even with just 10 students named 0-9, I realized that depending on how I arbitrarily created groups I would get a different number of maximum possible distinct groups of 3 elements, and I did not understand what the true maximum was because I got different numbers depending on how I constructed the groups, but I have no intuition on how to generate groups that maximize the distinct groups possible. Are there other ways I can clarify? Thanks for your patience.